# Has_many nested form does not update db rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am setting up a blogging-type platform where a user can create an account, and that user has many posts, which should show up on the user/show page. I already had the posts and users tables set up, and added in the belongs_to & has_many relationships after the fact. When I submit the form, it alerts that "User account updated" but the post does not show up in the posts table. I think I must be missing something crucial.

Schema.rb

```
  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.string   "category1"
    t.string   "category2"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "image"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end

  add_index "posts", ["category_id"], name: "index_posts_on_category_id", using: :btree
  add_index "posts", ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.boolean  "admin"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

posts/new

```
<%= form_for current_user do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.fields_for :post do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: "title", placeholder: "Post Title..." %>

    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, id: "edit" %>

    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? Can you post your UsersController?

Comment: Rails 4.1.8 , just added the code for the users_controller. There is a posts controller as well with basically the same stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by getting rid of the fields_for block and simplifying:

```
# posts/new

<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: "title", placeholder: "Post Title..." %>

  <%= f.label :body %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, id: "edit" %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

and adding this line to the create method in the posts controller:

```
@post = Post.new post_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id)
```

current_user is a previously defined helper method

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4 uses a pattern called "strong parameters" in the controllers to determine what attributes of an object can be mass-assigned. This is at the bottom of your UsersController:

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Then notice that in the `create` action this is being called on the line with `@user = User.new(user_params)`. Since you are using nested attributes to create posts along with a user, you need to whitelist the post attributes along with the permitted user attributes, which you can do by passing a hash where the key is the name of the child object and the value is an array of the attributes that need to be whitelisted for that object. Try this:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, post: [:title, :body])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are allowing only user parameters to store, for nested attributes also permit post parameters. Replace your user_params method with following code:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, post_attributes: [:title, :body])
end
```